# Como personalizar o Jwplayer com funções em Javascript

Tags: javascript, reprodutor-de-video

Alguem poderia me dizer como posso complementar o código do meu Jwplyer para realizar as seguintes atualizações.

Adicionar uma função que salve o tempo de execução do vídeo em um arquivo de cookie utilizando javascript com validade de 2 dias.
Juntamente a função pedida, adicionar em conjunto uma mensagem que seja ativada no player perguntando se o usuário deseja retornar o vídeo no ponto em que ele parou, apenas se o arquivo de cookie existir.

```
<div id='jplay'style='width: 100%;'></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var playerInstance=jwplayer("jplay");
    playerInstance.setup({
        localization:{fullscreen:"Tela Cheia", hd:"Qualidade", copied:"Copiado", playbackRates:"Velocidade da reprodução", videoInfo:"Sobre este vídeo", rewind:"Voltar 10s", settings:"Qualidade","loadingAd":"Carregando anúncio",},
        playbackRateControls:"[0.25, 0.5, 0.75, 1, 1.25, 1.5, 2]",
        id:"jplay",
        controls:true,
        displaytitle:true,
        width:"100%",
        height:"100%",
        aspectratio:"16:9",
        fullscreen:"true",
        autostart: false,
        preload:"auto",
        sharing:{heading:"Compartilhar"},
        image: jw.image,
        sources: 'arquivos de video aqui',
        type:"video/mp4",
        tracks:[{file:"",label:"Português",kind:"captions","default":true},

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obter a posição atual do vídeo pode usar [`jwplayer().getPosition()`](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-javascript-api-reference#jwplayergetposition) (no seu código algo como `playerInstance.getPosition()` e para detectar a mudança de posição do quadro atual do vídeo use o evento [`jwplayer().on('seeked')`](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-javascript-api-reference#jwplayeronseeked) (no seu código algo como:

```
playerInstance.on('seeked', () => {
    console.log(playerInstance.getPosition());
});
```

Pode salvar com [**`localStorege`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) ao invés de cookies e provavelmente vai querer salvar referenciando-se ao ID próprio do vídeo (se é que o vídeo possui ID), algo como:

```
playerInstance.on('seeked', () => {
    localStorage.setItem(idDoVideo, playerInstance.getPosition());
});
```

Se for baseado na URL do vídeo pode fazer assim:

```
playerInstance.on('seeked', () => {
    const file = playerInstance.getPlaylistItem(playerInstance.getPlaylistIndex()).file;

    localStorage.setItem(file, playerInstance.getPosition());
});
```

E quando recarregar a página e o player é claro, deve usar `localStorage.getItem` e aplicar o valor resgatado em [`jwplayer().seek(position)`](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-javascript-api-reference#jwplayerseekposition), algo como:

```
let firstPlay = true;

playerInstance.on('play', () => {
    if (firstPlay) {
        firstPlay = false;

        const file = playerInstance.getPlaylistItem(playerInstance.getPlaylistIndex()).file;

        const seekTo = localStorage.getItem(file);

        if (seekTo) playerInstance.seek(seekTo);
    }
});
```

Se ao chegar no final do vídeo você desejar apagar o `localStorage` especifico use o evento [`jwplayer().on('complete')`](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-javascript-api-reference#jwplayeroncomplete), exemplo:

```
playerInstance.on('complete', () => {
    const file = playerInstance.getPlaylistItem(playerInstance.getPlaylistIndex()).file;

    const seekTo = localStorage.removeItem(file);
});
```

Se precisar de mais ajustes específicos veja a **documentação: https://developer.jwplayer.com/jwplayer/docs/jw8-javascript-api-reference**